# npm compressing module to compress two subfolders

Tags: node.js, tar

I need a **.tgz** with the following folder structure:
**./folder1/folder2/ *"multiples files here"***.

The first folder will never contain files but is necessary.

I want to use the *"compressing"* npm module ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressing ).
But when I use it like in the following code, only folder2 is included. When I create another folder before folder 1 its the same, only folder2 is in there.

```
const compressing = require('compressing');

try{
    compressing.tgz.compressDir('/folder1/folder2', 'destination.tgz')
}catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```

I also tried to only specifiy the path to folder1 in the compressDir function, but then I get an error *"TarStreamError: ENOENT: no such file or directory"*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because your path is incorrect. you are giving the function the path `/folder1`, meaning it tries to find the folder in the ROOT directory because of the initial `/`. instead use `./folder1` or just `folder`.